# Another PInvoke - error message says source not found?

Tags: c#, c, struct, pinvoke

The struct that i have built in c# when run against the function does not give me one of the error message that tell me something is wrong with the struct.  It says that a source file could not be found.  Again, I don't know much about this DLL b/c of lack of documentation.  But I am still thinking it is because I set the struct up wrong. Most likely i'm thinking the 3rd struct where it is referencing a struct within the struct.
i was hoping for some feedback on the work I did. 
Thanks for the assistance.

This is what was provided in C:

```
int BatchTotal_Transactions(int transType, pTGiftCardReqBatchTotal req, pTGiftCardRespBatchTotal resp, int (*Com)(char *));

typedef struct _tagGiftCardReqBatchTotal
{
char Password[9];
char OperatorID[9];
char BatchNum[14];
char StartDate[11];
char EndDate[11];
unsigned char Type;
} TGiftCardReqBatchTotal, *pTGiftCardReqBatchTotal;


typedef struct _tagGiftCardRespBatchTotal
{
char Result;
char TerminalId[17];
unsigned char DispMsgControl;
char DispMsg[256];
char Display[41];
char Date[11];
char Time[9];
char RespCode[4];
char BatchNum[14];
char ErrorFlag;
char CustLang;
char UserLang;
char OpenDate[17];
char ClosedDate[17];
char StartDate[11];
char EndDate[11];
char BatchStatus;
int CardTypeNum;
TGiftCardTotals GctHost[MAX_CARD_CODES];
TGiftCardTotals GctTRS[MAX_CARD_CODES];
} TGiftCardRespBatchTotal, *pTGiftCardRespBatchTotal;

typedef struct _tagGiftCardTotals
{
unsigned short CardCode;
unsigned short PurchaseNum;
long PurchaseTotal;
unsigned short RefundNum;
long RefundTotal;
unsigned short RedemptionNum;
long RedemptionTotal;
unsigned short CorrectionNum;
long CorrectionTotal;
long PurchaseBenefitTotal;
long RefundBenefitTotal;
long RedemptionBenefitTotal;
} TGiftCardTotals, *pTGiftCardTotals;
```

And this is how I did it in C#:

```
[DllImport("batch.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  public static extern int BatchTotal_Transactions(int transType, ref giftCardReqBatchTotal req, ref giftCardRespBatchTotal resp, IntPtr com);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct _tagGiftCardReqBatchTotal
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
        public string Password;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
        public string OperatorID;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string BatchNum;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string StartDate;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string EndDate;

        public byte Type;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct _tagGiftCardRespBatchTotal
    {
        public byte Result;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
        public string TerminalId;

        public byte DispMsgControl;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string DispMsg;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 41)]
        public string Display;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string Date;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
        public string Time;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
        public string RespCode;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string BatchNum;

        public byte ErrorFlag;

        public byte CustLang;

        public byte UserLang;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
        public string OpenDate;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 17)]
        public string ClosedDate;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string StartDate;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
        public string EndDate;

        public byte BatchStatus;

        int CardTypeNum;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1024)]
        public _tagGiftCardTotals GctHost;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 1024)]
        public _tagGiftCardTotals GctTRS;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct _tagGiftCardTotals
    {
        public UInt16 CardCode;

        public UInt16 PurchaseNum;

        public int PurchaseTotal;

        public UInt16 RefundNum;

        public int RefundTotal;

        public UInt16 RedemptionNum;

        public int RedemptionTotal;

        public UInt16 CorrectionNum;

        public int CorrectionTotal;

        public int PurchaseBenefitTotal;

        public int RefundBenefitTotal;

        public int RedemptionBenefitTotal;
    }
```

Comment: That's not a pinvoke error message.  Maybe a debugger message, that's expected.  Quoting the *exact* message and where you see it is essential.  Post a screenshot.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/1z3qtrn/5

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the error:

http://tinypic.com/r/1z3qtrn/5

It says the file is in e:\teamcity ... 
But the key here is there is no reference to "teamcity" on the laptop but the file it is looking for is definitely in a referenced DLL which is not part of the DLL that is associated with the structures above.  
The only thing i can think of is struct is badly formed and is causing it to do something funky. Why would an independent DLL that we got from one vender (with little documentation) calls a function from another vender? just doesn't make sense.

Comment: The error is caused by the debugger trying to find a .CS source file, it's not the root cause of the problem. Just run the app and show us the exception stack trace.

Comment: I didn't think of the stack trace. UGH! Here is a screenshot. http://i39.tinypic.com/rwhox5.jpg It's an object not set to a reference.  So it comes back to my thought of it being the struct within the struct. Could that still be the problem because i don't instantiate that b/c it is inside the struct?
Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the error isn't the following:

> Specified module could not be found.

If this is the error then it is because the dll could not be found.  Make sure the dll is in your path:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.value.aspx